# Mongoose NodeJS only undefined values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

Now I've played with nodeJS and SocketIO and all went fine.
But now I get caught at one query!

```
// User Auth Event
socket.on('userAuth', function(userObj) {

     var queryUserAuth = User.find({
         name : userObj.name
     })
     .where('password',userObj.pword);
     queryUserAuth.exec(function(err, userData){

        if(err) {
            socket.emit('userAuthOK',err);
            console.log('!! User: %s or PW not OK', userObj.name);
            return handleError(err);
        }else {
            console.log('User: %s known, userID: %s', userObj.name, userData.userid);
            socket.emit('userAuthOK', userData.userid);
            socket.join(userData.userid); // Create new room / join this room
        }
     });

});
```

But all the time the var "userData" is empty and the console.log above tells me "User: testuser known, userID: undefined".
I can't get this user object from MongoDB this ways, but I can find the user if I take the mongo console.

///////////
EDIT:
After some changes... here the new code... but still without finding the right record and getting a result of null.

```
// User Auth Event
socket.on('userAuth', function(userObj) {
     var queryUserAuth = User.findOne({
         name : userObj.name,
         password : userObj.pword
     });
         //.where("password").equals(userObj.pword);
    queryUserAuth.exec(function(err, userData){

        if(err) {
            socket.emit('userAuthOK',err);
            console.log('!! User Auth Error: %s', err);
            return handleError(err);
        }else {
            if(!userData){
                console.log('!! User: %s or PW not OK.', userObj.name);
                socket.emit('userAuthOK','fail');
            }else {
                console.log('User: %s known, userID: %s', userObj.name, userData);
                socket.emit('userAuthOK', userData);
                socket.join(userData.userid); // Create new room / join this room
            }
        }
     });

});
```

Here the output by manual query on mongo shell:

> db.user.find({name: 'testuser', password: 'test'}) { "_id" : ObjectId("55a8cc8240fdc97f108d4d11"), "userid" : "1", "name" : "testuser", "email" : "test@test.com", "password" : "test" }

And this is the value of userObj: { name: 'testuser', pword: 'test' }

/////
EDIT2:

here the user.js including the mongoose model of User:

```
// Load the MongoDB module
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// user schema
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userid: Number,
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    status: Number
});


// compiling the user schema
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

// make this available to our users in our Node applications
module.exports = User;
```

Here the include of the model:

```
// Load Mongoose models
var User = require('./models/user');
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for ALL users? Are you certain that you've connected to the correct database in your node.js code?

Comment: Yes, I did. All is fine and other queries running without any problems.

Comment: @JohnnyHK:
You are my HERO! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try logging `userData` instead of just `userData.userid`. It's an Array, not an Object. You want to use `.findOne()`, not `.find()`.

Also, the syntax for the query methods is:

`.where("password").equals(userObj.pword)`

Or, you could just add it to your original `.findOne()`:

```
var queryUserAuth = User.findOne({
    name: userObj.name,
    password: userObj.pword
    });
```

In addition, your `console.log('!! User: %s or PW not OK', userObj.name);` doesn't make any sense. Not finding anyone is different than getting an error. You'll want to handle that part as a separate `if` statement nested within the `else` block.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried this way, too with result of NULL... userObj doesn't show anything, but NULL.

Comment: Your mongoose syntax is correct excluding the `.find()`. EDIT: I misread it, it should be `.where("password").equals(userObj.pword)`

Comment: @km65 I'll update my answer

Comment: I've changed the query but still null. :-(

Comment: @km65 can you add `userObj` as well as mongo shell document you are finding to your post?

Comment: I don't know if I get the right you need... but this is the mongo shell output by manual command:
    > db.user.find({name: 'testuser', password: 'test'})
    { "_id" : ObjectId("55a8cc8240fdc97f108d4d11"), "userid" : "1", "name" : "testuser", "email" : "test@test.com", "password" : "test" }

And this is the userObj:
{ name: 'testuser', pword: 'test' }